# How can I install a ruby gem (foreman) in a python virtualenv for my django project? And do I need to?

Tags: django, heroku, virtualenv, foreman

I am trying to follow the instructions here: http://honza.ca/2011/06/install-ruby-gems-into-virtualenv

However, I cannot find the `postactivate` script on my system. This link: http://bruno.im/2011/sep/29/streamline-your-django-workflow/ suggests that there should be a file called `~/.virtualenvs/postactivate`, but it is not on my system.

I have installed virtualenv and have set up a django app with the following structure:

```
django-project/
    .git/
    .gitignore
    blossom/              # top of my django project
        __init__.py
        blossom-sqlite3-db
        manage.py
        onora/            # my actual django app
            __init__.py
            models.py
            tests.py
            views.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    requirements.txt
    virtualenvironment/
        .Python@ -> /System/Library/Framework... 2.7
        bin/
        include/
        lib/
```

I would now like to add gunicorn to my requirements.txt file, install it with pip, and then create a procfile with the following line (as per heroku instructions at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using_a_different_wsgi_server):

```
web: python blossom/manage.py run_gunicorn -b "0.0.0.0:$PORT" -w 3
```

My understanding is that in order to use a procfile on my local system, I will have to install a ruby gem called `foreman`.

I have a couple questions.  First, do I need to install foreman in this virtual environment at all?  I need the virtual environment so that I can keep everything neatly contained for deploying to heroku.  The foreman gem is only for running things locally, if I understand what's going on correctly.  So perhaps I don't need foreman installed in the virtual environment.  Second, if it would be better for me to install foreman in the virtual environment, how can I find the postactivate file that I am supposed to have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postactivate is part of [virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper), a tool that builds on top of virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a great guide here http://blog.praveengollakota.com/47430655 for those who are interested.  Title is "Installing python 2.7, easy_install, pip, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on Mac OS X"

Comment: Here's a tip that did the trick for me: http://honza.ca/2011/06/install-ruby-gems-into-virtualenv